# Shortest non-null bash quine

Tags: bash, quine

The shortest `bash` quine is the null string:

```
$ bash -c ''
$
```

What is the shortest non-null `bash` script which produces its own source code as output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**19 characters:**

```
$echo 'echo $BASH_COMMAND' > quine
$ wc -c quine
19 quine
$ cat quine
echo $BASH_COMMAND
$ bash quine
echo $BASH_COMMAND
$
```

The character count includes the newline in the source (because it is produced in the output).

---

If you've not heard of `$BASH_COMMAND` before, [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Variables) says:

> BASH_COMMAND
>
> The command currently being executed or about to be
>   executed, unless the shell is executing a command as the result of a
>   trap, in which case it is the command executing at the time of the
>   trap.

Comment: I thought I had discovered a new shortest, as the [shortest quines list](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/69/58256) currently says `Bash - 20 by LinusKrom`, but LinusKrom also gives this same 19 character solution [here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/96563/58256).

Answer (score 0):

I feel like:

```
cat $0
```

should work but they dont accept it

Comment: this is a hole in code golf named "quine". the comment on the accepted solution references it

Answer (score 0):

I think I just stumbled on a bash quine, which may be the shortest non-empty one, though cheating a little bit:

you write a file like this:

```sh
#!/bin/cat
```

do `chmod a+x` on the file

then do ./file

the output will produce the contents of the file itself lol

Comment: That's not Bash, though. It's Unix notation to specify the interpreter of a script.

Answer (score 0):

**18 Character Bash Quine**

```
history|tail -c18
```

Note: this is a cheating quine (like "$BASH_COMMAND") because it inspects its own source code. It uses `history` to read in the bash history from RAM then grabs the last 18 characters

```
echo 'history|tail -c18' > quine
$ wc -c quine
18 quine
```